# Looking for efficient battery supply to power 3.3V circuit

Tags: power-supply, batteries, low-power

I have been searching everywhere for the best way to power my circuit and I can't find straight forward information.

My circuit needs 3.3V and the maximum current it draws is 50mA.  It will run at 50mA approx 1% of the time and 99% it will run at .004mA (not including the draw of the regulator).

I'd like the physical size to be something close to 3 AA batteries (or smaller).

It has to be rechargeable, have high capacity 3200mAh or more (5000mAh would be great).

So far the best information I see is to use a li-ion rechargeable battery and a [TPS63031](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS63031) voltage regulator.  I would like some input regarding if this will even work and if it is an efficient way to power my circuit or if there are better ways.

Comment: Is it practical to let the voltage 'droop' below 3.3V? Many microcontrollers have quite a wide range of operating voltages, and you might be able to take advantage of that too.

Comment: I noticed when it gets below 2.8v it starts to have problems.

Answer (score 1):

At such low currents, it would be much more efficient to use a linear regulator. If you use a lithium based battery with it you will not be able to get 100% from it because the circuit would stop running once you get below 3.4V on the battery. I'm a fan of TI's TLV70033 LDO.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was under the impression the regulator will step up the voltage when the battery gets below 3.3v.  Does it make sense to use a lithium based battery? What would you use when mAh is a high priority?

Comment: How many days should the battery last on one charge? The average current you are looking at is: 50mA x 1% + 0.004mA x 99% = 0.5mA. A 3200mAH battery will last approximately, 267 days. At 267 days, this limits your battery options. A NiMH rechargable has too high of a discharge rate. So the best option is lithium based.

Also, by the time you reach 3.4V, not much is left on the battery. Here is a good link describing how much juice is left on a [lithium battery](https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/voltages). The reason I am hesitant about switching supplies is that they carry

Comment: - a lot of overhead when you are supplying 0.004mA.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I just ordered samples of the LDO you recommended.  Any recommendations or advice for a battery?

Answer (score 0):

A [LP2985-33](http://www.ti.com/product/lp2985-33) doesn't need an inductor, will be much less noisy, and is much cheaper. It probably won't be as efficient when the battery is full, but will excel when it reaches 70-80% capacity (which is useful when the battery doesn't get fully charged in order to prolong product life).

Comment: Would I still get the total mAh that the lithium battery is rated for with this regulator? I'm not stuck on using a lithium battery/regulator combo. How would you power this circuit when mAh is a major concern?

Comment: No, you won't. But the switcher won't either. If I wanted to eke every last bit of energy from the battery then I'd make sure that the circuit can work with 3.0-3.6V and then use a 3.6V LDO which will ride the battery down to 3.2V or lower.

Comment: It will handle 3.0 - 3.6v.  Is the lithium-ion battery a good choice?  I was thinking something like this [link] (http://www.dx.com/p/sony-18650-2600mah-rechargeable-lithium-ion-battery-green-4-pcs-320780?tc=USD&gclid=CKOJnuSp7MACFcZQ7AodLz4AAQ#.VBuhdvldWSo) About how much of the 2600 mAh would you expect to get out of it?

Comment: It's hard to say without doing the math, but I would estimate... somewhere between 1600 and 2000mAh?